# Motorola MC3090 mobile computers draining battery fast when used with HP E-MSM430

Tags: hp, windows-ce

We used to use a consumer-grade stand-alone Linksys WRT54GL with our Motorola (Symbol) MC3090R mobile scanners, and the battery life would be about 6 hours of continuous wireless scanning.

Now we are using a centrally-managed enterprise wireless using HP E-MSM430 access points controlled by a central MSM760.  Since changing the have found that the battery life on the scanners has halved to around 3 hours continuous use.

It doesn't seem to make any difference what encryption type I am using (I have tried both WPA2 and open (no encryption)).

Any ideas what might be happening here and how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The more advanced radios can to a certain degree manage their power and encourage connected devices to use certain power levels.  Your new equipment also supports 802.11n, have you tried forcing your clients to not go higher then 54Mb/s?

Comment: There are very few config options in the Motorola wireless management software on the Windows CE client (Fusion 2.57.0.0.018R-CE-PHOTON).

It looks like there are more options on the MSM760, but nothing I can see that relates to power levels or transmit rates for the clients.

Comment: Right, but I am suggesting that there may be power/frequency settings you can force from your `MSM760 Access Controller`, but I am not familiar with that hardware.  I use Aruba equipment.

Comment: I'm going to try increasing the Beacon Interval on the E-MSM430 from 100 millisecs to 200 milliseconds and see if that helps.  I might also increase the DTIM count from 1 to 5.  I'll report back in a few days or so...